# Use of commas with repeated coordinating conjunctions that share the same subject

Tags: commas

What is the rule for using commas with repeated coordinating conjunctions that share the same subject?

Example (how to punctuate this sentence without rewording it):

> I woke up early and then washed my face and went to the store.

Comment: How many independent clauses do you see here?

Comment: To elaborate on @tchrist's technical analysis, a common rule is that independent clauses should be separated by commas. In your example the latter two clauses don't have an explicit subject and are therefore dependent clauses. Commas should not be used in this situation.

Comment: Of course, the question relates to CCs, not clauses. Let's not digress.